# Connecting an oven

Tags: wiring, walls, kitchens, oven

i'm trying to connect my oven.I live in Europe,Greece so the voltage is 220-240.Behind the oven there are 5 screws which you connect and tighten the wires.But i don't how which one goes where.I have to connect 3 wires(i guess number 5 screw is the ground wire).So,can someone help me to connect it?

Thanks.Here are some photos.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have single phase 240V power, you connect hot to screws 1, 2 and 3.  Neutral to screws 4 and 5.  That is what the diagram is showing.

And of course, ground to the ground screw.

Comment: Yes i have single phase 240v power.But i have only 3 wires to connect.Maybe i don't get something right here...?

Comment: The three wires you have are hot, neutral, and ground. You will need to connect the 2 and 3 screws to the 1 screw with short jumpers, and the 4 and 5 similarly.

Comment: They are already connected via solid copper U bridges.Now where should i connect the wires exactly?

Comment: @Zaz Please converse politely and not as if Stack users owe you help.

Comment: @zaz if there is already a connection between the 3 left screws, and another between the two left screws, it doesn't matter which of the screws in each set you use.

Comment: @zaz and if you are still not sure, add a picture of the actual terminal block and screws.

Comment: @Grant Okay, sorry about the delay but i went to the house where the oven is today. Here are two photos,the wires coming from the wall and the oven screws terminal. Thanks again! http://imgur.com/97736rb,FfACt6G

Comment: @zaz those U shaped bits are already connecting each set of screws, so as I said you can just connect your hot to screw 1 (or 2 or 3, doesnt really matter) and neutral to screw 5.